# Rails 5 in prod: PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" with Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker-compose

I am seeing the following error on my Linode server (Ubuntu 17.04) when starting up my Rails app:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

The odd thing is that this is only happening on my remote server. Locally (on my Mac), it's working fine. I have the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "${DATABASE_NAME}"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
volumes:
  postgres-data:
    driver: local
```

which should bind Postgres to port 5432 on localhost and set the password to the DATABASE_PASSWORD environment variable. If I run `ps aux | grep 5432` on the server I can see the Docker process is running correctly:

```
root     29550  0.0  0.2  34472  2888 ?        Sl   01:34   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 5432 -container-ip 172.18.0.3 -container-port 5432
```

So I cannot figure out why I'm getting a password authentication failed error message.

My config/database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: localhost
  username: postgres

...

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

The variables are set in my environment and I am able to echo them properly from the shell.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Was /var/lib/postgresql/data empty when you first run the docker-compose?

Comment: `/var/lib/postgresql/data` doesn't exist on either my dev or prod box. Isn't it a directory within the Docker container? I wouldn't know how to access it to check

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much head-bashing I solved the problem. Not sure exactly how but the following seemed to work:

Installed ntp just to make sure time settings were ok

```
$ sudo timedatectl set-ntp no
$ sudo apt-get install ntp
$ sudo ntpq -p
```

specified a Redis image version

```
redis:
  image: redis:4.0
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

then tried destroying all the Docker images

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
```

and finally tried to restart Docker

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Seems to be working as intended now.

Comment: I had the same problem and I was able make it work after deleting containers, images and volume.. I didn't need to change image version or add unix package.. I think deleting the old volume was what make it work. +1